# Equation spacing issue with fleqn (amsmath) and frenchb (Babel)

Tags: spacing, amsmath, babel, mdframed, french

*This is a follow-up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71668/highlight-equations-in-a-typographically-correct-manner).*

Here is an exemple of the code I wrote to add a light gray background
to important equations:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
% \usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

% Coloured background
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newmdenv[backgroundcolor=black!3!white,
          linewidth=0pt,
          innerleftmargin=0pt,
          innerrightmargin=0pt,
          innertopmargin=0.2\baselineskip,
          innerbottommargin=0.2\baselineskip]{graybck}


\newcommand{\highlighteq}[1]{#1}
\newenvironment{highlighteqenv}{%
\noindent
\vspace{0.2\baselineskip}
\begin{graybck}
}
{\end{graybck}}

\begin{document}
He said : ` you must defeat Sheng Long to stand a chance' which more or less amounted to
\begin{highlighteqenv}
  \begin{equation}
      \frac{\partial \langle \alpha K \rangle}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial z} =0
  \end{equation}
\end{highlighteqenv}

\end{document}
```

Quite strangely, it produces a wrong spacing before the equation, as
displayed on the following picture:

[image: Spacing problem]

Removing either the `fleqn` option of `amsmath` of the loading of
`babel` with the `frenchb` option solves the problem :

[image: Good spacing]

I would expect `frencb` to cause such issue with
something regarding paragraph indentation but why does it interact
with `fleqn`?

Do you have any idea to prevent this additional space from appearing
while keeping these two options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This shows a problem which is not related to `mdframed`, but appears with the `french` module in `babel` whenever you start a math environment in vertical mode *together with* the `fleqn` option; the space would be added also with the input

```
He said : `you must defeat Sheng Long to stand a chance' which more or less amounted to

  \begin{equation}
      \frac{\partial \langle \alpha K \rangle}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial z} =0
  \end{equation}
```

(notice the blank line)

A paragraph is started anyway, so a "solution" (which is more of a hack) is to backup manually:

```
\newenvironment{highlighteqenv}
  {\par\vspace{0.2\baselineskip}
   \begin{graybck}
   \leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}\ignorespaces}
  {\end{graybck}}
```

You don't need the `\noindent` anyway; better, though, adding a `\par`.

However, I'd suggest to use the standard spacing used for math displays:

```
\newenvironment{highlighteqenv}
  {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}
   \begin{graybck}
   \leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}\ignorespaces}
  {\end{graybck}\vspace\belowdisplayskip}
```