# \leftbar color specification

Tags: color, environments

I'm trying to use the \leftbar feature, but I would like the document to support two different bar colors.  [This issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22526/regarding-the-leftbar-environment/22528#22528) gets the color set, but only a single global color.  I would like some \leftbar to be red, others to be blue.  Right now I am doing this:

```
 % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22526/regarding-the-leftbar-environment
\renewenvironment{leftbar}[1][\hsize]
{
    \def\FrameCommand
    {
        {\color{blue}\vrule width 3pt}
        \hspace{0pt}
    }
    \MakeFramed{\hsize#1\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore}
}
{\endMakeFramed}
```

I want something like:

```
\leftbar{color{red}}
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

[EDIT - ADDED FINAL CODE]

```
\renewenvironment{leftbar}[2][\hsize]
{
    \def\FrameCommand
    {
        {\color{#2}\vrule width 3pt}
        \hspace{0pt}
    }
    \MakeFramed{\hsize#1\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore}
}
{\endMakeFramed}
```

Then to use:

```
\begin{leftbar}{blue}
\end{leftbar}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
 \renewenvironment{leftbar}[1]
```

to

```
\renewenvironment{leftbar}[2]
```

then replace `blue` by `#2` and you can use

```
\begin{leftbar}{red}
```

Comment: Fantastic.  And I learned something about how to use the files better too.  Thanks!